# JUnit test case for the default package

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit, package

I am very new to Eclipse and Java and working on a java project that has the following structure

```
Src_folder
    --default package 
    |  --src (main )
    --package1
    |  --src1
    --package2
       --src2
```

I want to add a JUnit test case for each class.  I want to create the following structure for the test cases:

```
test_folder
    --default package 
    |  --src_test (main )
    --package1
    |  --src1_test
    --package2
       --src2_test
```

My question is, what do I name the package for the default package while creating the test case for class in `src`? Is it a standard practice to have the default package with the main function or is it a good practice to rename the default package to something to indicate the `entry`?

Answer (score 1):

Use of default package is highly discouraged. Even Eclipse prompts you if you try to use default package.
Default package indicates that developer is too lazy to add one line of package declaration and nothing else.
[What is default package?](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-is-the-default-package/126)

Answer (score 1):

```
src
   --some_package
     --some source files
   --package2
     --some other source files

testsrc
   --some_package
     ... same structure as src folder
```

This is the standard practice followed.

[**And use of default package is highly discouraged**](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http://www.coderanch.com/t/512937/java/java/default-package-discouraged-worry&ei=drk9UauPDYKrrAe8rYGQBw&usg=AFQjCNHYeZ4f0-hCVjPRkT0Dezu8rBIfUg&sig2=jgCiiSfQ5kuHZuVNyAycDA)

Answer (score 1):

The use of the default package is discouraged because you can not import anything from it.  In your case it is only a main method, so not so much a concern, but it is still better to at least give it a package name.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using maven or similar in order to get a standard directory layout. You can then generate eclipse project files from it.

http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-convert-maven-java-project-to-support-eclipse-ide/

Answer (score 0):

Testcases should be in the same package with the classes they test. This is needed to access the default visibility modifier, that is only visible within the package and reduces imports. So don't create new packages for tests, separate the classes in a own folder is enough and as everybody said: You should not use the default package. If you are allowed to change this, do so.